# Using SSIS (XML task) can we add an incremental id for a node in XML file in order to keep track of the records when the structure is flattened

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

I want to flatten a xml file but with child nodes, one can loose track of the parent node. I wonder if there is possibility to add an incremental id to the parent node to avoid this problem.

For an example here are the xml input and the desired xml output
https://github.com/mouj77/xml

Comment: Please post your code within your question, not in external links. In addition, explain what is the **specific** difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: 1-I have tried to post the code within the question but it wasn't possible: Too much code.
 2- I am just wondering if it is possible to have an id for a parent node. If it is possible, would u please send me a reference: no need to write my code

Comment: Use an identity template and the function generate-id() to add an attribute to all nodes then process with your flattening code

Comment: @KevinBrown. It worked. This is so obvious. Thank you very much